# how do i add a section inside a section in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

in a Laravel project I want to add a section inside another section I've tried with a `@yield` but didn't worked.
and now I have this code:

```
@section('form')
  <form>MY FORM</form>
@endsection
```

and I put it inside this:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
 <body class: my page
   @include('form')
 </body>
@endsection
```

but when it loads I only see what 'content' has but not the @include() part.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put `@section('form')` on your form.blade.php . Here's a simple example:

```
//index.blade.php
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <body class="my-page"> 
       @include('form')
    </body>
@endsection
```

On the Form element

```
    <form>MY FORM</form>
```

If you do this, here's what output will look like:

```
<body class="my-page"> 
   <form>MY FORM</form>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks!!!! that worked!, srry i cant give u up vote yet not enough reputation.

Comment: No problem. You have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
 <body class: my page
  @yield('form')
 </body>
@endsection
```

In Form Blade

```
@extends('index')
@section('form')
 @parent
 <form>MY FORM</form>
@endsection
```

Try like this